# Difference between »nach« and »gemäß«

Tags: preposition

I'm translating a patent-related document that oscillates between *nach* and *gemäß* when referring to sections of a law:

> Neuheit **nach** § 3 PatG
>   <sup>(novelty according to/under § 3 PatG)</sup>

but

> gewerbliche Anwendbarkeit **gemäß** § 5 PatG
>   <sup>(industrial applicability according to/under § 5 PatG).</sup>

Is there any reason for using different prepositions? Some subtle difference in meaning that I'm not aware of?

Comment: For my understanding, choosing between *nach* and *gemäß* is a mere matter of style (or rhythm of the sentence), and the two words can be used completely interchangeably. But let's see if somebody comes up with a more articulate opinion...

Comment: Oh, by the way, there are more options. Except *laut* (see Ad Infinitum's answer below) you can also use *nach Maßgabe von*, but then this will be your coming-out as a full-grown bureaucrat.

Comment: Neben "laut", was in der Antwort erwähnt wird, möchte ich noch "jdm/etw. zufolge" ins Rennen schicken. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In einem anderen [Forum](http://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache.de/austausch/forum/read.php?4,67778) wird eine ähnliche gleiche Frage gestellt. Die Antwort von Michael Redeker für die Frage ist;

> "laut", "gemäß" und "nach" sind Synonyme mit der ungefähren Bedeutung
>   "wie dort zu lesen" oder "wie es dort steht".
>
> [Schauen Sie in den Beitrag zu "laut2" im DWDS.](http://www.dwds.de/?kompakt=1&sh=1&qu=laut)
>
> Dort wird "laut" wie auch "gemäß" als "papierdeutsch" = "eher
>   schriftlich gebraucht" bewertet.
>
> Ich sehe einen kleinen Bedeutungsunterschied: "laut" würde ich
>   gebrauchen, wenn ich die Rede einer Person nacherzähle und "gemäß",
>   wenn ich die Maßgabe einer Vorschrift oder eines Gesetzes wiedergebe.
>
> Aber im Grunde sind alle drei Wörter synonym.

Comment: Deinen vermuteten Bedeutungsunterschied sehe ich nicht. Es gibt hier trotz der jeweiligen Wortherkunft keinen Unterschied zwischen geschriebenem und gesprochenen Wort im praktischen Sprachgebrauch. Man kann durchaus "laut dem Zeitungsartikel" und "gemäß dem Radiosprecher" sagen.

Comment: Einen Bedeutungsunterschied würde ich auch nicht sehen, solange es um *gemäß § 3* und *nach § 3* geht. Wohl aber einen Benützungsunterschied: Für mein Gefühl ist *laut dem Radiosprecher* zwar nicht schön, aber akzeptabel, *gemäß dem Radiosprecher* jedoch in der Wahl des Ausdrucks verunglückt. Grund: *laut* sagt, dass jemand etwas gesagt hat (ein Radiosprecher, ein Paragraph), während *gemäß* sagt, dass jemand etwas festgelegt hat. Der Paragraph legt etwas fest, der Radiosprecher nicht, er berichtet nur. Darum geht für mich *gemäß* bei ihm nicht.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann "Gemäß dem Radiosprecher wird er ab 15:00 Uhr nur noch Beatles spielen" - funktioniert auch gemäß deiner Vorschrift prima. Was er spielt, entscheidet er nämlich selbst. Die Bededeutung von "gemäß" als "nach Maßgabe von" ist übrigens nur *eine* Bedeutung dieses Wortes.